# Magento 2 Custom Import Remove Import Behaviour

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a custom import script that works fine.

I would like to remove one of the behaviors from the drop down menu.

As I dont want to allow for appends to the custom table, only replace or deletes.

[image: Custom Import Behaviour]

Answer (score 2):

So, found the answer

1. Create a new Folder:

YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Model\Source\Import\Behavior

2. Create a new file called Basic.php in this folder

in the funtion _toArray() I commented out the Append Option

```
public function toArray()
{
    return [
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE => __('Replace'),
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE => __('Delete')
    ];
}
```

3. In your import.xml change the path from the magento path to your new Basic.php file.

   `<entity name="import_custom" label="Custom Import - Product Price Matrix" model="YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />`

Regards
Brendan

Answer (score 1):

Enter Below code custom behaviorModel class file of your custom module.

for example :

VendorName\YourModuleName\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic.php

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return 'custom_module_entity';
}
```

Please note you can take any string except "custom";

Answer (score 1):

Both `toArray` and `getCode` function needs to be modified in custom behavior file. Here is the complete solution.

**etc/import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="promotion_price" label="Promotion Price" model="Unioncoop\CustomImport\Model\Import\PromotionPrice"
            behaviorModel="Vendor\CustomImport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/CustomImport/Model/Source/Import/Behavior/Basic.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomImport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior;

use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;

class Basic extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic
{
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND => __('Add/Update'),
            Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE => __('Delete')
        ];
    }

    public function getCode()
    {
        return 'promotion_price'; // add your entity name
    }
}
```